# How to customize individual data points on Primefaces line chart in jqplot?

Tags: charts, primefaces, jqplot

I know that it is possible to change the markerOptions of whole series in line chart but how should I proceed to change the appearances of individual data points?

I have come across [this example](https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/blob/master/examples/line-charts-variable-markers.php) where a `markerOptionsCallback` option can be used when creating the plot but I would like to use this on a plot that is already created.

Thank you!